# Separating TextView from the edges of its background in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

The question is pretty much already said in the title.

How do I separate the text from the edges of it's background? If the height and width are wrap_content, they are right next to the text. I would like to have a separation there. If I use specific numbers I feel like it'll look differently on different devices.

**EDIT:** As I see some people are confused in the comments, what I meant was padding. I just couldn't think of that word, but now I got it because of another user who put an answer down there.

Comment: Uh, What are you asking?

Comment: can you please add example screenshot or something for understand us what are you looking for ??

Comment: @MayurKarmur I think he is looking for padding/margin, I posted an answer.

Comment: I meant padding guys. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to "Separate" It from the edge of the BACKGROUND, You can set a padding/margin to the `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```

Since you mentioned you have more then 1 `TextView` next to each other This is how you can do it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World TWO!"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which will look like the following:

[image]